# Cannot write to MS SQL database using PHP ODBC connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, insert, odbc

Problem: I can successfully use a select query in PHP using odbc_exec, however, I can not execute an `INSERT INTO or UPDATE` query.

Resources: Windows Server 2003: IIS 6, SQL Server 2005.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('../_DSN/DSN_M.php');

$cnnOra = odbc_connect($strarrDSN['dsn'], $strarrDSN['username'], $strarrDSN['pswd']);
$res_slct = odbc_exec($cnnOra, " select * FROM person;") or die (odbc_errormsg());

odbc_result_all($res_sldr);

$sqlupd = "UPDATE person SET person_ame='Steve Woz' WHERE pk_person_ID = '32';"

$res_upd = odbc_exec($cnnora, $sqlupd) or die(odbc_errormsg());      
$res_cmt = odbc_commit($cnnora);

var_dump($res_upd);
var_dump($res_slct);
var_dump($res_cmt);

// close the connection 
odbc_close($cnnOra); 
?>
```

The output of the SELECT query displays and there is no errormsg or var_dump results on the page.

Here is the output from the SELECT query:

```
pk_person_ID fk_SSN    fk_qual1_ID fk_qual2_ID person_Name 
31           999999999 1           1           bobby buchier 
32           999999999 2           2           Frank Gifford
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What are the permissions on the account you're connecting with? What is the error returned by the database when you try anything other than a SELECT?

Comment: Also, it would surprise me if pk_person_ID is a String. The solution could be as simple as replacing '32' by 32.

Comment: and is your field named "person_ame" ??? isn't it a typo ?

Comment: The SQL Account that i am connecting with has permissions to write to the database.

pk_Person_ID is not a string, it is an int. However, I have tried it with and without single quotes and it does not change the outcome.  I have run the UPDATE SQL exactly as typed using SQL Developer and it executes fine.

person_name is a typo here, but not in the script....

Comment: @andrewsi I can't seem to get any errors to display.

Comment: @user2283350 - does `odbc_errormsg` return anything?

Comment: @andrewsi - Unfortunately, no.  In fact nothing below the odbc_exec for the UPDATE seems to execute...

Comment: @user2283350 - I've found a couple of references that suggest changing the table name to a fully-qualified one might help - so it'd be `SELECT * FROM database.schema.person....`

Comment: You might also want to see if you can split it into an `odbc_prepare` and `odbc_exec` call, and see if the error goes away then. Or if not, see which one it fails on.

Comment: @andrewsi was correct.  I needed to use an odbc_prepare and then an odbc_exec.  Here is the code that worked for me:

    $q = "UPDATE person SET person_name = 'Steve Woz' WHERE pk_person_ID = '32'";
    $res = odbc_prepare ($cnnOra, $q) or die (odbc_errormsg());


    $exc = odbc_execute($res) or die (odbc_errormsg());

Comment: @user2283350 - I'm glad that worked, though I can't understand why the original code didn't. You should add it as an answer and mark it as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for me.  I am not sure why this works when my original code didn't.

I needed to use an odbc_prepare and then an odbc_exec. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
$q = "UPDATE person SET person_name = 'Steve Woz' WHERE pk_person_ID = '32'"; 
$res = odbc_prepare ($cnnOra, $q) or die (odbc_errormsg()); 
$exc = odbc_execute($res) or die (odbc_errormsg());
```

This also works on a `INSERT INTO` query.  Much thanks to @andrewsi!!

Comment: BTW: once I started using this code, it started to return error messages.