# PHP/ODBC insert issues - no errors

Tags: php, insert, odbc

I am having trouble inserting data into an Access table ('test').  I have an html form that should use my PHP to INSERT.  Everything seems to go okay (no errors) but when I look at my Access table ('test') nothing has been inserted and I do not know why.  SELECT works fine, I just can't INSERT for some reason.

Thanks for the help.

test.html:

```
<html>
<body>

Enter Customer Information
<br>
(* indicates required fields)

<p>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Last Name*: <input type="text" name="last">
<br>
First Name*: <input type="text" name="first">
</td>
</tr>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('testdb','','');
$sql="INSERT INTO test (last, first)
VALUES
('$_POST[last]','$_POST[first]')" or die (sql_error);
odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die (exec_error);
odbc_commit($conn) or die (comm_error);
odbc_close($conn);
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

Comment: Does `odbc_errormsg()` return anything useful?

Comment: I just added it but it does not report anything.

Comment: Oh, I should have spotted that earlier.... You're not currently doing anything with `$sql` - you need to pass it in to `odbc_exec` to run it. Clearly I need more coffee....

Comment: I've added in the odbc_exec command (correctly I think?) but I still get the same result.  Did I do this right?  (I edited the original post with the odbc_exec added in)

Comment: That looks correct to me. Can you add in `var_dump($result)` on the following line, so you can see what you're getting back from the database?

Comment: It returns: NULL 1 record added

Comment: That's weird. `odbc_exec` will either give you a resource if it worked, or `false` if it failed - null shouldn't be an option. That's on the line right after the `odbc_exec`, right? Can you also try `var_dump($conn)`, too, just to make sure that the database connection is working?

Comment: Yes, it is on the next line.  I added the var_dump line and produced: NULL resource(1) of type (Unknown) 1 record added

Comment: I just typed `odbc_commit` into SO's search box, instead of google's, and it found a link to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020582/cannot-write-to-ms-sql-database-using-php-odbc-connection (which I'd completely forgotten about.) You could try the same, and split your call into two separate prepare and execute calls?

Comment: Ok, so I tried the update line and I've also added in "or die..." comments in case of a fail.  It fails consistently on the odbc_exec line, which I've changed to $exc = odbc_exec($res) or die (exec_error); and executed with a var_dump($exc);.  I get the 'exec_error' each time now, so I guess that is where its failing, I just don't know why.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you.

Comment: I just updated my post to show current test.php.  I now get an 'exec_error' message, which as far as I understand would indicate an issue with executing the insert command (because I've basically said that if it cannot complete the odbc_exec command, it should die and echo 'exec_error', as far as I understand it).

Comment: You can try `or die (odbc_errormsg())`, which should hopefully give you the error from the database connection - that should show what the problem is, hopefully.

Comment: Ok, I did that and we may be making some progress.  It returned: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query.  It seems like the database is acting like it's read-only, but the DSN admin window does not have read-only marked.

Comment: Problem solved.  After adding the odbc_errormsg line I got :[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query.

My ODBC admin window did not have 'Read-only' marked.  However, my access database was not allowing regular users to write or modify.  After adjusting permissions on the folder AND the *mdb file, it worked.  

Thanks to Andrewsi for helping me through this.  I will def be adding errormsg lines after each command from now on!

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you got it sorted - could you add what happened as an answer, and mark it as Accepted when you're able?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  After adding the odbc_errormsg line I got :[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query.

My ODBC admin window did not have 'Read-only' marked.  However, my access database was not allowing regular users to write or modify.  After adjusting permissions on the folder AND the *mdb file, it worked.

Thanks to Andrewsi for helping me through this.  I will def be adding errormsg lines after each command from now on!